# Python plugin: ogr2ogr count exported features after task completion and keep shell open

Tags: qgis, python, ogr2ogr

Periodically we import a shapefile with a Python QGIS plugin into PostgreSQL, which calls ogr2ogr in the cmd shell. After running it, the window disappears. Is there a way to count the features imported to PostgreSQL and keep the shell open? Or any other reporting mechanism in ogr2ogr?

We use the following statement:
 `ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG: "dbname='geo' port='5432' user='postgres' password='xxx'" -progress -append -nln public.test -nlt "C:\Users\Documents\Shape\shapefile.shp"`

Comment: Append: && pause at the end to keep the shell open: ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG: "dbname='geo' port='5432' user='postgres' password='xxx'" -progress -append -nln public.test -nlt "C:\Users\Documents\Shape\shapefile.shp && pause"

Comment: What would you like to achieve by keeping the ogr2ogr window open after conversion? What does the number of converted features have to do with this? org2ogr does not report such number. You can check the number in the shapefile with ogrinfo beforehand.  When ogr2ogr finishes all of them have been converted.

Comment: It's about giving feedback to the users. Our computers are so fast that the console only flashes once, but you can't see whether the import to Postgres worked or not.
But if the console stays open with ```&&pause```, the user sees either the error message or progress bar. Our users also have no further access to the database and therefore we are looking for a way to compare the imported features with those of the import. We will probably now solve it with direct database queries via Python. Will edit the post here when it is finished.

Comment: You probably know that you can also run ogrinfo with any SQL, for example `ogrinfo PG:.... -sql "select count() from updated_table as count"`.

Comment: Very good advice, I will take it into account.